# Inferencing in protege

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, protege

I have a simple ontology as follows

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
<!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >
<!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
<!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
<!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
<!ENTITY assignment "http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#" >
]>

<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#"
 xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment"
 xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
 xmlns:assignment="http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#"
 xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
 xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
<owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment"/>

<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Object Properties
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#channel_of -->
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&assignment;channel_of">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&assignment;Channels"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&assignment;Television"/>
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="&assignment;has_channels"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#has_channels -->
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&assignment;has_channels">
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&assignment;Channels"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&assignment;Television"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#has_inet_connection -->
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&assignment;has_inet_connection">
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&assignment;InternetConnection"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&assignment;Person"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#has_television -->
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&assignment;has_television">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&assignment;Person"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&assignment;Television"/>
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="&assignment;ownes_by"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#internet_connection_owned_by -->
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&assignment;internet_connection_owned_by">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&assignment;InternetConnection"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&assignment;Person"/>
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="&assignment;has_inet_connection"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#ownes_by -->
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&assignment;ownes_by">
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&assignment;Person"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&assignment;Television"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#watched_by -->
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&assignment;watched_by">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&assignment;Channels"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&assignment;Person"/>
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="&assignment;watches"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#watches -->
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&assignment;watches">
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&assignment;Channels"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&assignment;Person"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>

<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Data properties
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#yh -->
<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&assignment;yh"/>

<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Classes
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#Advanced -->
<owl:Class rdf:about="&assignment;Advanced">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&assignment;Coloured"/>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&assignment;ownes_by"/>
            <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="&assignment;Rich"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#Antena -->
<owl:Class rdf:about="&assignment;Antena">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&assignment;Channels"/>
</owl:Class>

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#BlackAndWhite -->
<owl:Class rdf:about="&assignment;BlackAndWhite">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&assignment;Television"/>
</owl:Class>

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#CRT -->
<owl:Class rdf:about="&assignment;CRT">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&assignment;Coloured"/>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&assignment;ownes_by"/>
            <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="&assignment;Mid"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#Channels -->
<owl:Class rdf:about="&assignment;Channels"/>

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#Coloured -->
<owl:Class rdf:about="&assignment;Coloured">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&assignment;Television"/>
</owl:Class>

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#High -->
<owl:Class rdf:about="&assignment;High">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&assignment;InternetConnection"/>
</owl:Class>

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#Internet -->
<owl:Class rdf:about="&assignment;Internet">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&assignment;Channels"/>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&assignment;channel_of"/>
            <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="&assignment;Advanced"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#InternetConnection -->
<owl:Class rdf:about="&assignment;InternetConnection"/>

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#LCD -->
<owl:Class rdf:about="&assignment;LCD">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&assignment;Coloured"/>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&assignment;ownes_by"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="&assignment;Rich"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#LED -->
<owl:Class rdf:about="&assignment;LED">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&assignment;Coloured"/>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&assignment;ownes_by"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="&assignment;Rich"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#Medium -->
<owl:Class rdf:about="&assignment;Medium">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&assignment;InternetConnection"/>
</owl:Class>

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#Mid -->
<owl:Class rdf:about="&assignment;Mid">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&assignment;Person"/>
    <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="&assignment;Rich"/>
</owl:Class>

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#Person -->
<owl:Class rdf:about="&assignment;Person"/>

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#Rich -->
<owl:Class rdf:about="&assignment;Rich">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&assignment;Person"/>
</owl:Class>

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#Television -->
<owl:Class rdf:about="&assignment;Television"/>

<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Individuals
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#John -->
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&assignment;John"/>

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#SLTA -->
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&assignment;SLTA">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&assignment;Advanced"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/shadowman/ontologies/2013/5/assignment#Youtube -->
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&assignment;Youtube">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&assignment;Internet"/>
    <watched_by rdf:resource="&assignment;John"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
</rdf:RDF>
<!-- Generated by the OWL API (version 3.4.2) http://owlapi.sourceforge.net -->
```

Now, I am going to infer that person `John` is a Rich Person. I tried various restrictions, but only I am getting that 'John is a person'.

My initial ontology idea is this, if person watches an Internet channel from his TV, then he has an advanced TV, advancedTV s are ONLY `owned_by` Rich people.

Now in our Instance, John watches YouTube, YouTube is an internet channel, so internet channels only available in advanced TV, and advanced TV s are owned only by rich, therefore John should be rich. But as stated earlier, I keep getting that John is a person

Comment: What reasoner are you using?  How are you querying the reasoner?

Comment: I used Protege inbuilt reasoner, also jena reasoner. Both gives the same result

Comment: Protégé can use a number of reasoners, including Pellet, FaCT++, and HermiT.  They should all work with the answer I provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not think that you can express this in your current class hierarchy using OWL alone.  If I understand correctly, you already have the axioms

```
John watches YouTube
YouTube a InternetChannel
InternetChannel availableOn only AdvancedTV
AdvancedTV inverse owns only RichPerson
```

but cannot infer the intermediate inference `John a (owns some AdvancedTV)` that would let you conclude that `John a RichPerson`.

If you had the additional axiom “if some person P watches some channel C, then P owns some television T and C is available on T,” then the reasoning would work as follows: “Since John watches YouTube, John would have to own some television on which YouTube is available.  Since YouTube is an internet channel, the television would have to be an advanced television.  Since John would then own an advanced television, he would be a rich person.”

### The limitation in OWL

However, I do not think that that axiom can be expressed in OWL. Descriptions logics (of which OWL is one) are a subset of first-order logic, and can only express first-order sentences that use only two variables.  The axiom above seems to require three:

- ∀ p, c: watches(p,c) → (∃ t: owns(p,t) ∧ availableOn(c,t))

I have not been able to rewrite that in such a way that it uses only two variables, so I do not think that it can be expressed in OWL.  That means that you will need to change something in your ontology to make this work.  As I see it, there are a few options:

- You could turn your channel class hierarchy and introduce some individuals to represent channel types.
- Instead of using a *watches* relationship that only related persons and channels, you could use a three place relation *watchesOn* that relates a person, the channel that they watch, and the television on which they watch the channel.

The first option might be a bit quicker to implement, but I think that the second option is a bit more flexible in the long run, better represents the information at hand, and makes for a cleaner overall representation.

### Representing Channel Types with Individuals

If you changed the channel subclass hierarchy into a collection of channel types, e.g., instead of `YouTube a InternetChannel`, you were to say `YouTube hasChannelType Internet`, then you say things like

```
watches some (hasChannelType value Internet) SubClassOf owns some AdvancedTV
```

which says that “if someone watches something that has channel type internet, then that someone owns an advanced television.” Since John watches YouTube, and YouTube has channel type Internet, then John owns an advanced television.  Since advanced televisions are owned only by rich people, John must be a rich person.

That axiom is a general class axiom.  It does not have a simple class name on the left hand side, but rather a class expression.  These do not come up all that often, but as discussed in [Being complex on the left-hand-side: General Concept Inclusion](http://ontogenesis.knowledgeblog.org/1288), they are *very* useful on occasion.
That article provides an example of creating them in Protégé, as well.  To enter a general class axiom in Protégé, go to the *Active Ontology* tab, and find the *General class axioms* tab within it.  Then you can enter the axiom verbatim, and it should look like this:

[image: General class axiom in Protégé]

### Changing *watches* to *watchesOn*

Alternatively, you can replace the binary relation *watches* with a 3-place relation *watchesOn* which would associate a person with with the channel that they watch and the television on which they watch it.  This has the nice advantage that in the case where an individual owns multiple televisions, some can still be primitive while others are advanced.  (The first solution just says that if someone watches an internet channel, then they own an advanced television, but it doesn't capture the fact that the person uses that television to watch the internet channel.)  To replace the binary relation *watches(Person,Channel)* with the tertiary *watchesOn(Person,Channel,Television)* we follow the approach given in the W3C Working Group Note, [Defining N-ary Relations on the Semantic Web](http://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/).  We introduce a *class* (not a property) *watchesOn*, each of whose instances represents an occurrence of the *watchesOn* relationship, and three properties, *hasWatcher*, *hasWatchedChannel*, *hasWatchedTelevision* which relate instance of *watchesOn* with the person, channel, and television, respectively, that are involved in the relationship.  Instances of *watchesOn* will often be blank nodes.  For instance, *watchesOn(John,YouTube,JohnsTelevision)* can be represented in RDF as:

```
[] a :watchesOn ;
   :hasWatcher :John ;
   :hasWatchedChannel :YouTube ;
   :hasWatchedTelevision :JohnsTelevision .
```

With this kind of representation, we can state lots of useful facts.  For instance, to say that if a person watches something on a television, then they own that television, we assert:

```
inverse(hasWatcher) o hasWatchedTelevision SubPropertyOf owns
```

This is like saying

> hasWatcher(?w,?person) ∧ hasWatchedTelevision(?w,?television) → owns(?person,?television) .

You can also say that televisions on which internet channels are watched are advanced televisions.  This requires a general class axiom, as in the first solution, but in this case, it is:

```
inverse (hasWatchedTelevision) some (hasWatchedChannel some InternetChannel) SubClassOf AdvancedTV
```

which is like saying

> hasWatchedTelevision(?w,?television) ∧ hasWatchedChannel(?w,?channel) ∧ InternetChannel(?channel) → AdvancedTV(?television) .

With both of those axioms in place, we can infer that `John owns JohnsTelevision` and that `JohnsTelevision a AdvancedTV`.  If we add one more class axiom, namely that if a person owns an advanced television, then they are rich, i.e.,

```
owns some AdvancedTV SubClassOf RichPerson
```

then we can infer that `John a RichPerson`.

This kind of representation is nice in that using restrictions, we can assert, for instance, that John watches YouTube on some television, without stating which television he watches it on.  This requires adding a type assertion to John, namely:

```
John a inverse hasWatcher some (hasWatchedChannel value YouTube and
                                hasWatchedTelevision some Television)
```

This says that John watches YouTube on some television, but does not say *which* television.  By our earlier axioms, the reasoner can still infer that whatever television it happens to be, it must be an advanced television, and John must own it.  The reasoner can then still infer that John is a rich person.

[image: A reasoner in Protégé confirms that John is a RichPerson]

This works even one step farther.  We do not even need to specify which channel John watched, but just that it is an internet channel:

```
John a inverse hasWatcher some (hasWatchedChannel some InternetChannel and
                                hasWatchedTelevision some Television)
```

and the reasoner can still infer that John is rich person.  To top things off, the class expression

```
inverse hasWatcher some (hasWatchedChannel some InternetChannel and
                         hasWatchedTelevision some Television)
```

consists of those individuals that watch some internet channel on some television.  The reasoner can tell us that this class expression is a subclass of `RichPerson`, which means that these kinds of inferences work not just for `John`, but anything in this class:

[image: Pellet confirms in Protégé that anyone who watches some internet channel on some television is a RichPerson]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but now I have some other question, that is how do you express `(watches some (hasChannelType value Internet)) SubClassOf (owns some AdvancedTV)` in protege ?

Comment: @user1479203 It's called a general inclusion axiom or general class axiom.  (They've been discussed in some other questions, such as [OWL Instance Participation Logic](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16816519/1281433) and [Representing if-then sentence in OWL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16496364/1281433).  In Protégé 4.x, you can add general class axioms under the main _Active Ontology_ tab which contains a _General class axioms_ tab.  I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: @user1479203 It occurred to me that another way to solve this problem is to replace the binary `watches` relation with a three-place relation `watchesOn` that more properly captures the relationship.  I've updated the answer to include the earlier approach and this new one.

Comment: @user1479203 Glad to hear it!  These sort of questions are great because its usually not more than a few months before I come across a similar problem, and each of these techniques ends up in the proverbial toolbox.  Happy inferencing!